# wp_Query with 4 post meta feald arguments gives 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a custom plugin to search for custom post type provided with 4 meta field arguments. I am using wp_Query() to fetch the search results. My Query string is.

```
$args = array(
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
        'cache_results' => false,
        'post_type' => 'caravans',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'caravan_used_new',
                'value' => $used,
                'compare'=>'like',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'caravan_or_motorhome',
                'value' => $type,
                'compare'=>'like',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'caravan_berth',
                'value' => $bearth,
                'compare'=>'like',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'caravan_make',
                'value' => $make,
                'compare'=>'like',
            ),
        )
    );
    if(!empty($key)){
        $wp_query = new WP_Query("s=$key", $args);
    }else{
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    }
```

Now it is working good if I put only three meta_Query arguments when I make it to 4 its start crashing and all I see in 500 internal server error. Am I doing something wrong or meta_query has its own limits?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem by replicating the whole setup to my local server.
Everything worked fine query executed normally. And the bug was memory allocated for PHP execution which i come to know by comparing the local and live server. 
So for that I declared two lines in the header part of the file.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");
```